# jupyter multiline equations do not export in html properly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Suddenly my `ipynb` does not compile properly into `html` leaving multiline equations as they are. Only yesterday things were fine and I have no clue as to what on earth might happen.

I've tried two versions:

```
    \begin{equation}
        y_{out} = f({y_{in}}) =
        \begin{cases}
            1, & \text{if $y_{in} > 0$} \\
            0, & \text{if $y_{in} \leq 0$}
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
```

and

```
    $$
        y_{out} = f({y_{in}}) =
        \begin{cases}
            1, & \text{if $y_{in} > 0$} \\
            0, & \text{if $y_{in} \leq 0$}
        \end{cases}
    $$
```

My compilation line looks like this:

```
jupyter nbconvert MyFile.ipynb --to slides --post serve --SlidesExporter.reveal_theme=simple --SlidesExporter.reveal_scroll=True --SlidesExporter.reveal_transition=none
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

### As per [Equation Numbering and References](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Equations.html#Other-Syntax)

- In a markdown cell in Jupyter

[image]

```
$$
y_{out} = f({y_{in}}) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $y_{in} > 0$} \\
0, & \text{if $y_{in} \leq 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
```

- Export Notebook to HTML, produces the following:

[image]

#### If your notebook worked previously:

- Try the equations in a new notebook to see if they work
- Try rolling back to a saved version when the notebook worked

  - The notebook may have become corrupted